# How to apply different Sales Tax rates to the same Membership Type - Back Office

Tags: price-sets, taxes

In Canada we need to charge Sales Tax depending on what Province the Member resides in. How can we do this in the Back Office. In other words: an administrator signing up a Member in CiviCRM.

Comment: I'd note that your solution works adequately well for public contribution pages as well, as long as you trust your members to select their province.

Comment: For public-> we use a select province/territory -> that creates a button (Purchase Membership now) that leads to  one of 4 Public Contribution/Membership Pages -> one for each Tax Rate :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with Price Sets. I'll document the entire set up:

1. Go to Administer -> CiviContribute -> CiviContribute Component Settings
   and check the box Enable Tax & Invoicing (Tax = Sales Tax; Invoicing you get as a bonus)
2. Go to Administer -> CiviContribute -> Financial Accounts 
   and create one Financial Account for each Sales Tax Rate

Ignore Tax-Deductible - it is not related to Sales Tax; it potentially could be used to track whether monies are deductible for Income Tax purposes but I don't recommend it [there are other ways to track that; will document that at some point]. Click Is Tax -> (Tax = Sales Tax) and enter the Tax Rate right below it.

[image]

Repeat until you have the 3 Financial Accounts needed (3 different Sales Tax rates):

[image]

3. Set up Financial Types -> And associate each one with a one of the Financial Accounts we just created. Note we can add a 4th one [for out of Country residents] - i.e. with no Sales Tax.

[image]

4. Next are Price Sets - create a Price Set - for each Membership Type/Sales Tax Option - Yes that's a lot of Price Sets. Let's look at one: in the Maritime Provinces the Sales Tax is 15% -> so we need to create a Priceset that has a Line Item that hooks up to the Financial Type that has the 15% Tax Rate associated with it:

[image]

Looking at the Individual Price Fields:

[image]

5. Putting it all together - in Back Office -> from a Contact Summary record -> Membership tab -> Add Membership or Create Credit Card Membership

[image]

And selecting that Priceset results in the correct Amounts

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks for the intensive writeup. I've been lurking around the CiviCRM tax issue for the better part of 8 years and even went so far as to write a somewhat limited extension to handle taxes before the concept of accounts arrived. I knew there was a method for this but I really needed someone to document it.

Comment: Hi Andrew! Thank you - 8y? Yikes... If you've come across any tips/tricks - please do document in SE. Would love to see them!

Comment: Hi Karen. Yeah, I know... 8yrs. Yikes is right. I know how to do some very specific things in Civi well. I can build extensions and extend Civi and expose all sorts of Civi things to Drupal but my weak point is the Accounts part. I'll be making an effort this year to wrap my head around that. Cheers.