# Can we print an invoice without GST?

Tags: contributions, invoice

We have a client who wants to bill an Australian Member with Ireland HQ, therefore they need to provide an invoice without GST as head office is paying. Is there any way we can tick or untick GST when creating a payment? Thanks.

Drupal 7.59 CiviCRM 4.7.38.

Comment: What you mean with GST?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sales Tax (like GST) is per Financial Type so if you need to make an invoice without GST you need to make the Contribution of a Financial Type that has no GST associated with it.

Have a look here for details on how to set up different sales tax rates for the same membership type:

[How to apply different Sales Tax rates to the same Membership Type - Back Office](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25815/how-to-apply-different-sales-tax-rates-to-the-same-membership-type-back-office/25816)